# Show dfsdatabase in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

```
db=database("dfs://valueDATABASE", VALUE, 2006.01.01..2006.01.31)
getDFSDatabases()
```

It didn't show database "dfs://valueDATABASE".

Answer (score 0):

`getDFSDatabases` only shows distributed databases that contains concrete data.